# How can i change "SlidesPerView: 4;"?

Tags: javascript, css, swiper.js

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".new-arrival", {
  slidesPerView: 4, 
  centeredSlides: false,
  spaceBetween: 30,
  autoplay: {
    delay: 5500,
    disableOnInteraction: false,
  },
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
    type: "fraction"
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
  }
});
```

i want to change SlidesPerView: 4; to SlidesPerView: 1; when its gonna be max-width 390px how can do it?

Comment: replace number `4` with number `1`? What is the question again?

Comment: i want to change when its @media(max-width:390px){} in css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your code.

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".new-arrival", {
  slidesPerView: 4, 
  centeredSlides: false,
  spaceBetween: 30,
  breakpoints: {
  390: {
    slidesPerView: 1,
    spaceBetween: 0
  },
  autoplay: {
    delay: 5500,
    disableOnInteraction: false,
  },
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
    type: "fraction"
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
  },

});
```

Comment: @OkanEmre you're welcome. please accept the answer by click the check so this is case closed :P :)

Comment: it didnt work can you help me?

Comment: @OkanEmre Try to add that entire code above.

Comment: its not working :(

Comment: try the one above

Comment: it workedddddddd

Comment: great thats a good news :) Happy Coding.